# grid controls for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid

If you are using ASP.NET MVC how are you doing grid display?
Rolled your own?
Got a library from somewhere?

These are some of the known grid display solutions I have found for ASP.NET MVC

- [ASP.NET MVC Flexgrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVCFlexigrid.aspx)    - Has nice column layout method
- [Code based ASP.NET MVC GridView](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/06/04/code-based-aspnet-mvc-gridview.html) - simple, small, clean
- [MVC Contrib](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/07/23/asp-net-mvc-grid-view-using-mvccontrib.aspx) - grid from codePlex
- [jQueryGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page%5Fid=6)  - jQuery grid
- [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/)  - jQuery plugin - believed to be section 508 compliant ([.NET binding](https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables))
- [extJS](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html) - cross browser RIA framework - has grid support
- [Ingrid](http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/) - jQuery data grid
- [jqxGrid](http://jqwidgets.com/) - jQuery data grid
- [Telerik MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/) - jQuery based grid that is GPL v2 licensed, commercial version also available
- [MVC Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/) - Client Site Based Grid
- [Infragistics igGrid](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/jquery-controls/grid.aspx) - jQuery based MVC grid
- [dhtmlxGrid](http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/?p=1349) - Ajax-enabled JavaScript grid control
- [ASP.net MVC Awesome Ajax List](http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/Dinners) - a different, very flexible approach, can be used as a grid
- [Syncfusion MVC Grid](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/sfmvcsamplebrowser/10.2.0.56/Grid_MVC/Samples/4.0/Razor) - Commercial grid
- [ASP.net MVC Awesome Grid](http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/GridDemo) - part of the Awesome library (jQuery based)
- [Shield UI Grid for ASP.NET MVC](http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/grid-general/basic-usage)
- [Grid controls for ASP.NET MVC 5 projects](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/)

If you know of anything else that you are using or know to be good, please let me know.

Comment: I was hoping of a grid with javascript support but which could nicely degrade to a full GET request if the JavaScript is disabled. However I will have to build my own :(

Comment: I would go with Datatables or jQuery grid

Comment: couldn't agree with you more.. i've had well voted questions closed as well, but i was surprised this one was too.  getting good up votes should speak for how constructive a question is. that's not enough to these moderators as they're over-eager show us what's constructive and what is not.

Comment: Yeah, this question is very constructive to me.  But they always close questions that ask which library is the best to use.

Comment: It remains pretty astonishing to me that these "moderators" seem to think they know what's useful better than the people who, umm, find them useful.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. con·struc·tive
adjective
1.
serving a useful purpose; tending to build up.

Comment: ASP.NET / IQuerable support for datatables.net here:  
http://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables

Comment: hate these "not constructive" type closes.  total bs.

Comment: https://jsgrids.io/ is a list of data grid libraries. You can filter the results to only show jQuery-specific libraries.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We have been using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) on a project and have had some good luck with it.  Lots of options for inline editing, etc.  If that stuff isn't necessary, then we've just used a plain foreach loop like @Hrvoje.

Comment: Hi @SeanCarpenter- Any suggestion for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34003053/2404470)

Comment: Note that this is a commercial product and and the download is 30 days trial.

Answer (score 29):

We use [Slick Grid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) in Stack Exchange Data Explorer ([example containing 2000 rows](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/9548/select-top-2000-from-posts)).

I found it outperforms [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and [flexigrid](https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid). It has a very complete feature set and I could not recommend it enough.

Samples of its usage [are here](https://wiki.github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/examples).

You can see source samples on how it is integrated to an ASP.NET MVC app here: https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Comment: It's very nice and performant, but only if you are going to *always* use simple data and columns (I find myself adding some touch as rowspans, graphics, etc to some tables to make them nicer)

Comment: Looking to the samples... it seems that you can do lots of things with this grid... I liked...

Comment: are you still using slickgrid?

Answer (score 24):

We have just rolled our own due to limited functionality requirements on our grids. We use some JQuery here and there for some niceties like pagination and that is all we really need.

If you need something a little more fully featured you could check out ExtJs grids [here](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html).

Also MvcContrib has a grid implementation that you could check out - try [here](http://code.google.com/p/mvccontrib/). Or more specifically [here](http://code.google.com/p/mvccontrib/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/MVCContrib/UI/Grid/UI/Html/Grid).

Comment: Also used extjs before. Really liked it using it.

Answer (score 16):

I just discovered Telerik has some great components, including Grid, and they are open source too.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/

Comment: I spent the last day working with the Telerik grid, and it's pretty nice, if you can manage to stay on the ever-elusive "happy path."  However, my app uses restful routing (i.e., where my deletes would post to "/controller/{id}" with an Http Method override of DELETE), and that was apparently too far off the "happy path" for the Telerik grid to be useful to me, and their code is too tightly coupled to cleanly override its behavior through inheritance, etc.

Comment: It should be noted that the terms of their Open Source product means it should only be used on GPLv2 Compatible Open Source projects. That rules out a lot of commercial applications - if you want to stay legal :)

Comment: I was never happy with Telerik components. They look good and work with standard functionality, but things get worse when you try doing something which is not part of demo. You may check their Kendo UI. It's heaps better, but still not perfect

Answer (score 12):

If it's just for viewing data, I use simple foreach or even aspRepeater. For editing I build specialized views and actions. Didn't like webforms GridView inline edit capabilities anyway, this is kinda much clearer and better - one view for viewing and another for edit/new.

Comment: I agree. I don't like inline editing in a grid either.

Comment: And from UX point of view, it's better to have more small screens then one big and complex. Also that fits better to good server side code design (OOP), because you can have separated behaviors for screen commands, and not one big db.Save(pageData), moving toward verbs on domain model, unlike "just" bunch of model CRUD methods.

Comment: I too agree as I do not like inline editing. Separation of concern eases the task.

Answer (score 7):

We use the MVCContrib Grid.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/08/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-using-the-mvccontrib-grid-and-pager.aspx

Comment: I had seen you tutorial code in one of the rss feeds. It was helpful to me on a project I just started.

Answer (score 7):

jqGrid is $299 if you use a special version that has server side integration, but it really is not that difficult to use the open source free version with ASP.NET MVC, once you get your jquery configuration straight it's almost as simple to use as any other licensed grid:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can use also the Insert/update/delete datagrid of my MVC Controls Toolkit available here on codeplex:
http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/. [Here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/releases) you can download a complete example, [here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid%20and%20Pager%20Complete%20Example) the datagrid working and [here](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2010/10/30/Defining-MVC-Controls-2-Using-the-DataGrid.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2010/11/15/Defining-MVC-Controls-3-Datagrid-Sorting-and-Master-Detail-Views.aspx) tutorials. The DataGrid works completely client side and mantains thechange set between posts. Yes it mantains Changeset, this means, you can access both old version and modified version of each record to see what changes to pass to the DB(what need to be modified deleted or inserted). This Changeset is mantained after several posts till you either confirm or cancel the modifications on the server side.

Answer (score 5):

If it is read-only a good idea would be to create a table, then apply some really easy-but-powerful JQuery to that.

For simple alternative colour, [try this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-table-manipulation-part2) simple JQuery.

If you need sorting, [this JQuery plug-in](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) simply rocks.

Comment: yes. I saw this. Scott Hanselman was talking about this when Phil Hack posted his repeater helper code in this article : 

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/03/code-based-repeater-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: I think that's how I found out about the first link as well!  Most of the grid stuff I do now is mostly done on the client.  Scott's tip was well taken.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the example [here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid%20and%20Pager%20Complete%20Example) of the Mvc Controls Toolkit grid. It appears a quite powerful and easy to use grid. The tutorial not only explain how to use the grid but also how to do paging, organize a view model and data annotations. It is worth to read it.

Answer (score 3):

Try: http://mvcjqgridcontrol.codeplex.com/
It's basically a MVC-compliant jQuery Grid wrapper with full .Net support

Answer (score 2):

Check out the grid from [Infragistics jQuery controls](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/jquery-controls.aspx#Overview)

Here is a ASP.NET MVC sample with code:

http://labs.infragistics.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid/AllFeatures

Comment: Thanks. Will add to list above.

Comment: Mike, you can add the following to the list: http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/jquery-controls/grid.aspx

Comment: I have updated with a link to the igGrid from infragistics. sorry for the delay as I have been away for thanksgiving. igGrid looks interesting.

Comment: Coming from someone who's tried to use this in a production app, I would not recommend this grid.  It's buggy, poorly documented, and there's virtually no community support, possibly because it's not open source.  Most of the features (sorting, column resizing, etc.) have issues with them that involve various work-arounds and compromises.  The Winforms Infragistics grid we'd used in the past worked great, but I'd steer clear of their web version until it's more baked.