# In search of a grid for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I'm searching for a robust lightweight grid for ASP.NET MVC. I'd rather not write a grid, if someone else has done it,but I have yet to find a decent grid. It should be 508 compliant and for the most part, 508 compliance eliminates all the JavaScript grids.

- It has to be easy to use.
- Not too expensive ( a couple hundred
  dollars )

I've already reviewed the following grids:

- [Ext Js](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html)
- [MvcContrib](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/07/23/asp-net-mvc-grid-view-using-mvccontrib.aspx)
- [jQueryGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)

**Update**

I found a javascript grid that performs the magic I am looking for yet, maintains 508 compatibility.

It's a jQuery plugin called [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/). It takes a preexisting table on the page and gives it sortablity and search features. Other grids would either render the table themselves or make ajax requests to the server.

Comment: How relevant is the "MVC" part to your question?  Either the grid is built server-side or client-side.  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/asp-net-mvc-grid-control

Comment: No it is not. I need a grid that is 508 compatible. The grids they suggested won't work because they depend on JavaScript, hence the "already reviewed grids"

Comment: Did you see MvcContrib's grid? it doesn't require javascript AFAIK.

Comment: I did. The problem is it embeds logic (implementation, ie. for loop,  ) in the presentation. I can do the same thing myself without embedding code in the presentation.

Comment: @Charles

could you briefly mention how the datatables grid is able to maintain 508 compliance? I have seen 508 start popping up at work so I am curious to know

Comment: what did you find wrong with the above three that didn't match your requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVCFlexigrid.aspx

there are also

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/06/Code-based-ASPNET-MVC-GridView.aspx
http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/

Comment: It appears that the first and third links use javascript, which *might* violate the 508 compliance as stated in the question.  However, the second link looks like pure server side generated HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The Yahoo YUI Library DataTable control supports "[progressive enhancement](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_enhanced.html)".  You output a standard HTML table.  This displays just fine on browsers with JavaScript disabled.  On browsers that do support JavaScript, the table replaced with an enhanced version that can support client-side sorting and other presumably other fancy things (I've only ever used it to enable sorting).

Answer (score 1):

I just came across [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx) detailing the use of jQuery Grid with ASP.NET MVC.  It's a great overall strategy for dealing with the grid, it even details even the more difficult filtering capability of jQuery Grid!