# Datagrid choices in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [grid controls for ASP.NET MVC ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc)

Hi, I just started using asp.net MVC and I'm looking for any good Grid Html helpers  or libraries to use with it similar to Web forms datagrid control, I have just used MVC contrib grid so far. Thanks.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: jQuery? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Have you prove Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC?

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've used jqGrid (jQuery) with success on asp.net-mvc projects

http://www.trirand.com/blog/