# Asp.net gridview MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

Can i create a gridview control in Asp.net MVC,and set its DataSource propertie and DataBind  method,mormally as in web forms?

Comment: I don't know about grid, but you can take a look at this pager - seems it is quite nice. http://en.webdiyer.com/MvcPager/Demo/JqAjaxOrders

Comment: You might find this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

No - ASP.NET MVC has no ViewState and therefore no native WebForms controls will work.

There are a number of hybrid approaches for people who wish to use controls in MVC but if you wish to work in that way it would be better to use WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible - wrap the grid inside a `<form runat="server">` tag and you are back in the WebForms business - ViewState, postback etc. However I would too not recommend this approach. You better use a mixed WebForms-MVC approach. You can also check the available grid solutions for MVC.