# ASP.Net Gridview control with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, objectdatasource

I've a requirement to use ASP.Net Grdview control in ASP.Net MVC. Now I need to handle form submit action.I'm using Objectdatasource for filling my grid. Now when I submit, I need to have current state of my grid data which includes checkboxes checked state.

Answer (score 8):

The old ASP.NET controls are made to work with traditional web forms and processing through postback.  ASP.NET MVC doesn't use postbacks so they won't work together well.  You can use the controls for displaying data well enough, but getting processing on the server will be prohibitively complicated.

You'll be much better off using a grid control designed specifically for ASP.NET MVC.  Here's a good question with links to several:

[grid controls for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc)