# Edit/Update a single GridView field

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I've got a GridView on an ASP.NET page, on which I need to edit a single field in a row when a user clicks the 'Edit' button on that row, and have a SQL database table updated with whatever the user enters.

I'm added a CommandField to my GridView, so I now have an 'Edit' button at as the last column in each row. I'm getting the data from the database using LINQ.

**My question is** - how do I wire it so that when I click this 'Edit' button, the user is allowed to edit a single item in this row, then update the database with the text the user enters?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried anything - I've been looking for an example but can't find one - that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: try Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=gridview+edit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Thanks, but I'm well aware of Google! My problem is all the examples I find don't mention ASP.NET MVC, which is what I'm using.

Comment: GridViews are not used with MVC

Comment: OK, I'm upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 3 right now so I can use WebGrid...

Comment: @Jimmy C, then update your question. When I see the `asp.net-mvc` tag and a GridView being mentioned I know there is something wrong going on. So one of those two should disappear as they don't play well together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some Grid options for use with ASP.NET MVC:

[grid controls for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Set the fields you don't want to edit to read only:

```
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerName" />
```

Comment: I've set the these, but when I click the Edit button nothing happens?

Comment: @Jimmy C: When you say "nothing happens," does the page not even postback or do you mean the read-only field is still editable?

Comment: The page postback happens, but the field isn't editable. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: You have at least one field with ReadOnly="False" right?  (You have at least one editable field?)