# ASP.NET MVC2 Grid Control (VS 2010)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How do you use the grid control in ASP.NET MVC2? I am using VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the standard asp.net webforms grid?

becuase you can not use that grid, because it relies on the viewstate and that is not available in asp.net mvc

Comment: I want to use any grid control supported by ASP.Net MVC pattern.

Comment: hi, i found this question which sums up a lot of grids you can use with asp.net mvc. Be aware that the usage of a grid in mvc is different then in webforms: no server events! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc