# jQuery Grid with Tag/Autocomplete column

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I am looking for a jQuery grid that allows having a "tags" editable column. My tags are taken from a list of possible values (coming in json).

I have basically being looking at the components in this post [grid controls for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc) and more.

I am close to some implementation using [jqxGrid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/defaultfunctionality.htm) and a tags library since jqxGrid allows to render my own values for columns - however, I am having many conflicts. This post is not to resolve such conflicts (I am still trying to do that) - it is to know if there is a jQuery grid out there that supports that feature built in.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the JQGrid, very customizable, lots of support for it on stackoverflow via the infamous oleg of course :) I've used it for quite a while now and its been very useful. [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and [JQGridWiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) , I can't recall offhand if that feature is built in

Comment: We saw it before. Looks way too complex for what we want. Still, didn't know it had good support. We'll check it out more deeply. Thanks.

Comment: Cool man, once you've worked with it for a while its a pretty easy grid to customize. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm yet to see a better jquery grid than DataTables. Have a check on www.datatables.net