# jQuery Grid In SEO

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, grid, seo

I want to use jquery grid in asp.net MVC in my project, I would like to know what is good and bad point in jquery grid?

As a side note, SEO is very important for my project and if your comment is bad point, please suggest me best grid in asp.net mvc.

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc?rq=1) gives you a good start. The question would be easier to answer, if you could tell us which features you need.

Comment: I need use grid in asp.net mvc and I dont konw which grid component is good and flexible.

Comment: The post I linked before list 15 grid components and all have their pros and cons. So it depends on what you want, do want need: filters, grouping, aggregations, edit features, how many data do want to display, must it be responsive, how customizable should it be, open source  or not, ODATA support etc. We can't make this kind of investigation for you.

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid is a JavaScript library, and as we all know, search engines are not executing JavaScript. Not to mention that you are probably using AJAX to fetch data from server.

I'm sorry to tell that but in order to make your web page SEO-friendly you need to create JavaScript-free version displaying the same data. Obviously when user enters that page by accident he should be redirected to JavaScript version.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [jTable](http://www.jtable.org/). Its Free and you could able to modify the code to satisfy your SEO needs. Its a pure javascript prototype model.