# Return All Rows/Column Data from Data Set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dataset

I'm designing an ASP.NET MVC 4 solution that will allow a user to import an Excel file, make specific modifications to it on the page, and export the file in the same format.  I'm trying to make a View called Grid that will display the contents of a large Data Set which contains all of the data from the Excel spreadsheet.

```
    public ActionResult Grid()
    {
        DataSet ds = TempData["DataSet"] as DataSet;
        string exampleCell = ds.Tables[0].Rows[3][2].ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

exampleCell is an example of how I am extracting single cells from the table.  I imagine I can iterate through all of the columns and rows in the Data Set and extract all of the data using this approach.  How, then, can I display all of the exampleCells on a single View?

Comment: This is a confusing question. That the data originate in Excel is a distractor. Maybe it originated in FoxPro or punched cards. The point is you already have a DataSet and need to display a table of data in MVC. Here is an (unfortuantely closed) question that mentions many ways to display data in a HTML table for MVC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I removed some of the mentions of it being a DataSet derived from an Excel spreadsheet - although I'm still not sure if I'm using the correct approach, with regards to the fact that the DataSet is displaying data from an Excel spreadsheet.  Nevertheless, I don't know how render the contents of exampleCell on a view, nor display n x m exampleCells on a view.  Do any of these libraries do this with a DataSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be far better off creating a Model for what you're iterating over. This will allow MVC to generate the Model when your user clicks Save on the client side.

So you'll have a class that will encapsulate the values in each row. Have another Model which will have an IEnumerable/IList of your first Model you created.

In your Controller method, convert the DataSet to these models, and then pass the model with the collection to your View. Populate your HTML grid/table by iterating through the enumerable.

If you want to save all of the user's changes in one shot, wrap your grid/table in a form, and use the same Model (with the IEnumerable) as a parameter for the POST method. That will populate the entire model back for you when it calls the server again.

That might be a little unwieldy to try and figure out what changed (unless you just want to do a single mass data dump again), so if you want to save each action, that'd be just as easy to do with single client side AJAX calls.

Comment: Agreed.  It would seem more like an act of get it done quickly than an act of get it done right to bind directly to a data set.  If you want a "get it done quickly" binding like that, web-forms is probably the way to go, not MVC.  I wonder if the default model-binder could even handle a dataset?

Comment: Agreed about web-forms if you want to work with a DataSet like that. Part of the entire attempt at solving this all depends too on how the data is being gotten from Excel (which was abstracted from the OP's question). If you're on the web, you shouldn't be using the native Excel COMs as they aren't designed for server use. Something like EPPlus would be a much better solution, and it would be more work trying to get the information into a DataSet than working with it as model objects.

Comment: Of course, it's entirely possible that code is already set up to provide a DataSet from the data source, so the entire discussion of the ease of getting into a List, and avoiding Excel COM could be moot.

Comment: @krillgar Thank you for the detailed answer; it's probably apparent that I'm a little new at this.  I think I follow everything - I was avoiding using a model because the spreadsheet has over 100 columns, but I believe that in this scenario I can use a string array to represent the contents of each row.

Comment: There's a reason there's an "M" in MVC. ;) A string array could work, but an object would be far easier to work with in the View.