# GridView in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a GridView in MVC5 to view Data and Also add some Drop down list to filter the Data and show the result in GridView. I wasn't able to find any good example for Grid view in MVC. Should I use GridView at all or just try to use Table?  and how I can find a good tutorial about it? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/177275/3743442) is a full list of available grids for MVC, old but still in most extends valid. But personally I had the best experience with [Grid.Mvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) . It is free, easy to handle, with professional formatting styles and very freindly filter options for almost every type of data.

Comment: thanks, I tried to use Grid.Mvc but I have some error in this line:@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>  ... In (Model) it gave me: The type argument for methos 'GridMvc.Html.Grid<T> cannot be inferred from usage. Try specify the tyoe arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old question, you can achieve displaying grid using following ways-

1. Simple grid design using foreach loop and html table: Iterating
   table's tr tag. This is pretty simple and basic way of displaying
   records.
2. Webgrid : Provided by System.Web.Helpers class which render
   data in tabular format with supported feature like sorting,
   pagination and filtration.
3. JqGrid : It's a jquery plugin. It support many advance feature which grid view should have.
4. Kendo UI : This is from Telerik which is not free.

You can refer [this post](http://www.dotnetpoints.com/gridview-in-aspnet-mvc-6) for more details and demo.

Comment: Kindly provide the reason for down-vote.