# Export the Table View in an Excel sheet in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I want to export the Excel sheet of my Razor view table. This code shows the table:

```
public ActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<GradeSheetViewModel> model = _repGrade.GetList(id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the code for export to Excel function

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        var gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = this.Show();
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
        gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return View("Index");
    }
```

but it gives the error at

```
gv.DataSource = this.Show();
```

the error is

> no overload for the method Show takes 0 argument

Comment: The method Show has one parameter id and you call it without parameter.

Comment: how can i call it with parameter inside the function ?? @Jean-ClaudeColette

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

`DataSource` property assignment requires `IEnumerable` as its source. You need to change `Show` method to return any objects that implements `IEnumerable` (e.g. `List`) and call it with `id` parameter like this:

```
// Get list object
public List<GradeSheetViewModel> Show(int id)
{
    return _repGrade.GetList(id);
}

// Controller
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(int id)
{
    var gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = Show(id);

    // other stuff
}
```

**Additional note 1:** If you want user to download the file you should return file as `FileResult` instead of adding `Response` and returning view:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(int id)
{
    var gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = Show(id);
    gv.DataBind();

    // save the file and create byte array from stream here

    byte[] byteArrayOfFile = stream.ToArray();

    return File(byteArrayOfFile, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "DemoExcel.xls");
}
```

**Additional note 2:** Avoid using webforms server controls like [`GridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) in MVC controller. You can choose one of available alternatives from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc).