# LINQ show result as array

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm using the following code to join 2 tables and return their results to the `View`.

```
var Results = (from post in DbContext.posting_file
                  join reader in DbContext.user_master_postings on post.id equals reader.posting_id
                  join file in DbContext.postings_title on post.id equals file.id
                  orderby reader.date_created descending
                  select new { file.title, reader.date_created, reader.department, reader.user_name }).Take(5).ToArray();
```

***When running the foreach loop in the view.***

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Results){
    @item
}
```

***I get the following result.***

> ```
> { title = Title 1, date_created = 21/08/2018, department = Audit, user_name = Chetty }
> { title = Title 2, date_created = 21/08/2018, department = Audit, user_name = Pal }
> { title = Title 3, date_created = 21/08/2018, department = Audit, user_name = Chetty }
> { title = Title 4, date_created = 21/08/2018, department = Corporate, user_name = Kau }
> ```

What I want is the result to be in array format so that I can loop over the results and populate it inside the table. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - the result _is_ an array and you're printing each item. If you want to create a table you can either create `<tr>` elements in the loop (and then create `<td>` elements for each property), or search for "ASP.NET gridview" (or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275)) and use one of the many third-party products that do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely what you are asking however if you wish to populate the contents of an array (which you are specifying using `.ToArray()` in your LINQ query), you can use the following dot notation inside a loop.

p.s. You probably want to include some headers in this table, but you get the idea.
p.p.s Have you considered incorporating this collection inside a viewmodel rather than in the viewbag?

```
@if (ViewBag.Results != null && ViewBag.Results.Count > 0) {
        <table>
        @foreach(var item in ViewBag.Results) {
        <tr>
           <td>@item.title</td>
           <td>@item.date_created</td>
           <td>@item.department</td>
           <td>@item.user_name</td>
       </tr>
   }
      </table>
}
```